# How can I access user likes information using Graph API?

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to use facebook Graph API to fetch user details.
    Below is my FB.api query :

```
FB.api('/me', 'GET', { access_token: token, fields:'id,name,email,gender,location,likes' }, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    alert(response);
});
```

With above query i am able to fetch id, name and gender but not location, email and likes.

Version for FB SDK : v2.5

I think the issue is related to some permissions required to fetch such private data of user.

Please suggest what need to be done to get all the data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask for the permissions in the login process, with the scope parameter. Here is a list of those: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions

Here´s how to use FB.login with additional permissions:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        //user just authorized your app
        document.getElementById('loginBtn').style.display = 'none';
        getUserData();
    }
}, {scope: 'email,user_likes,user_location'});
```

Source: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Make sure you read about Login Review too: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review

Comment: Thanks luschn.
With above scope parameters I am able to fetch email data but still cant find user_likes as well as location. Do i need to give some more permissions..?

Comment: are you trying with a regular user or a user with a role in the app? you must read about login review, follow the link in my answer and read everything there, it is important.